# C# ExcelWorksheet cell value is read incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am parsing a csv file using C# and ExcelWorksheet.
I have a cell that contains an integer. `3020191002155959391100`

When I parse the cell using

`var value = sheet.Cells[rowNumber, columnNumber.Column].Value;`
value is `3.0201910021559592E+21`

when I parse the cell using sheet.Cells[rowNumber, columnNumber.Column].Text;
the value is `3020191002155960000000`

how do I prevent the rounding off?

Comment: `3020191002155959391100` is a too big for an `int`. But when you do `.Text`, it is read as a `string` hence you get the complete value.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: @Sach but then how do I convert that to a long or double or some non float ? to get the actual value of 3020191002155959391100

Comment: Even `long` max value is smaller than this. public: long MaxValue = 9223372036854775807;
Why do you want to store such a large number as an int? You should probably use it as a string if it's an ID.

Comment: I don't want to store as an int necessarily. When I read it as a string (.Value) it is already in E notation, that is where I start from... I can not work with E notation. How do I get string of "3020191002155959391100". Is what I am trying to do explained clearly enough?

Comment: I think that's because in yoru Excel file you have the cell type as either `General` or `Number`. You'll need to set it to `Text` in the Excel first, then the string reading should work fine.

Comment: What is the library that `ExcelWorksheet` is in btw?

Comment: it is a csv file I am parsing so no cell type per say. namespace OfficeOpenXml is the package

Comment: If it's a CSV file that you're using, then you're using the wrong tool for the job. Use a CSV parser such as `CSVHelper` which you can find in NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value of an `int` in C# is

> int.MaxValue: 2,147,483,647

Source: https://www.dotnetperls.com/int-maxvalue

Therefore your number is too big to be read as an `int`.

However, upon reading your comments it appears that you're using the Excel reader to read a `CSV` file, which is the wrong tool for the job. Use a `CSV` parser such as `CSVHelper` (https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) which will make your life easy.

Here's an example of how to read such long numbers as string using `CSVHelper`.

First I'll create a class to match your CSV file. I created a dummy CSV file that looks like the following. Simply, three long numbers in a row.

> 3020191002155959391100,3020191002155959391101,3020191002155959391102

Now I create a class like so:

```
class CSVRecord
{
    public string Data1 { get; set; }
    public string Data2 { get; set; }
    public string Data3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can read all the records in one go. Note the `csv.Configuration` settings, depending on the complexity of the file you read you'll have to change those. I advice you to read the documentation and examples on the link provided.

```
var file = @"data.csv";
var records = new List<CSVRecord>();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
{
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
        records = csv.GetRecords<CSVRecord>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set the specific column types to string, before processing each cell.

```
columnDataTypes.Add(eDataTypes.String);
```